# Retrieving rating scale values in code

Tags: c#, sharepoint, scale, rating

I made a survey to register the knowledge inside my organisation. e.g.:

Question:

Microsoft Development;

Subquestions:

SharePoint

CRM

WCF

etc...

People can rate their proficiency using a rating scale. The min value being 0 and the max value 6.

I wan't to retrieve the values from the responses in a new graphical feature.

I'm new to this and this is my code so far:

```
var thisWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;

foreach (SPList item in thisWeb.Lists)
{
    if (item.Title.Contains("Knowledge"))
    {
         foreach (SPListItem child in item.GetItems())
         {
             foreach (SPField field in child.Fields)
             {
                  Debug.WriteLine(field.Title);
                  if (field.TypeAsString == "GridChoice")
                  {
                      var ratingscale = field.GetFieldValue(field.);
                      //var x = ratingscale.GetFieldValue(ratingscale.Choices.ToString());
                  }
              }
           } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
  {
        if (field.Type == SPFieldType.GridChoice)
        {

        SPFieldRatingScale srsc = (SPFieldRatingScale)field;
        Debug.WriteLine(srsc.GetFieldValueAsText(item[field.Title]));

          }
      }
```

This will return you values in format below. 
question 1;#answer#question 2;#answer# .....

Comment: Great thats alot of help, i can work out a solution from here, but it would be even better if somehow i could put the value inside a SPFieldRatingScaleValue object. Do you have any idea on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance,

Comment: unfortunately I have never did it :(